# search and assign value based on text

Tags: excel

I tried  using  formulas (search, sumproduct, if) to search for a string and return a specific value. So in my example, if A1 contains string with  "AAA", return 1, if A1 text has "BBB", return 2 etc...Any ideas

```
text              value
MAINTENANCE AAA     1
MAINTENANCE BBB     2
CCC MAINTENANCE     3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your attempt to use SEARCH.

Comment: SEARCH along with IF should work. Please share the formula you tried.

Comment: The latest two are: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA",A2)),1,IF(SEARCH("BBB",A2),2,"Other"))` and `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"AAA*"},A:A))),1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"BBB*"},A:A))),2)`

Answer (score 1):

Make a table of texts and associated values, e.g. in Y2 you have `AAA` and in Z2 1, In Y3 `BBB`, in Z3 2 etc. then you can use this formula

`=INDEX(Z$2:Z$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Y$2:Y$10,A2))*(Y$2:Y$10<>""),0),0))`

[image]

Note: `SEARCH` is not case-sensitive - if you want the search to be case-sensitive then use `FIND` function instead of `SEARCH`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without having some kind of "mapping table" would be to use two arrays - one for text parts to look for and the other for values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({1,2},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"aaa","bbb"},A2)),0)),"Not found")
```

Where `{1,2}` is the array of values and `{"aaa","bbb"}` is the array of texts to look for and `A2` is the cell containing text to be searched.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!